# Why are my foreach loops in an ASP.NET MVC View so slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use a `foreach` in my View to loop over my strongly-typed Model and display a table.  With only 25 rows and 7 columns, it takes about 280 msec.  This seems slow.  Is there some performance trick I should know for using loops in Views?

EDIT: My Controller takes data from an Azure Table and feeds it to a View using a ViewModel pattern.  I don't know if this matters, but my Views are in VB and my Models are in C#.  So, they're in separate projects.  I'll come up with a slimmed down example to post, but I'm running out the door now and will have to get to this later this evening.  I was hoping I'd catch the StackOverflow crowd before people went home for the weekend, so my original post was made quickly without example code.

EDIT: I confirmed with Fiddler that there's no lazy loading happening.  There's no Fiddler activity during the rendering of the View.

EDIT: If I feed a View with data from an Azure table, it takes 280 msec.  If I feed the same View with fake data that looks just like real data from an Azure table, it takes 60 msec.  In either case, the Controller just populates a ViewModel object and passes it to the View.  The same ViewModel class is used in both instances.  I don't get it.

EDIT: I think I figured it out.  Perhaps this would have been obvious to everyone else if I had included code at first.  Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeChildrenViewModel
{
    public Employee employee;
    public IEnumerable<Child> children;
}
```

If I pass the above ViewModel to my View, the `foreach` takes 280 msec.  If I populate the above ViewModel with `children.ToList()` first, then the View only takes 60 msec.  However, upon further investigation I see that the overall page load time is the same in either case.  I guess it doesn't matter if the IEnumerable is iterated over in my Controller or my View since the overall effect is the same.  I'm still not sure what iterating over `children` does since I know for sure that it's not hitting the database at that point, as confirmed with Fiddler.

Comment: Tell us what you're looping over, maybe it is something heavy and you don't realize it. You haven't given us the information about the problem.

Comment: @eu-ge-ne & @Karl: Sorry, I should have done that at first.  Code posted now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Linq-to-SQL or some other ORM that by default loads lazily?

I suggest logging all database calls (`datacontext.Log` = some class that inherits from `TextWriter`) and check if associations are being loaded lazily when you iterate over them in the View.

**EDIT: It appears the below information is not relevant to this question, but I'll leave it here as it might be useful to someone:**

Gonna assume you're using Linq-to-SQL here (I'll edit this if this is not the case):

When your model foo has an association Bar (so foo.Bar) and you don't specify any LoadOptions in the datacontext, the Bar is loaded lazily (so: loaded when called, like probably happens in your View) which means the View essentially goes to the database. And this happens for every row.

Do something like the following:

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Foo>(f => f.Bar);
context.LoadOptions = options;
```

Further, to prevent this, try wrapping your DataContext in a `using` statement:

```
using(DataContext context = new DataContext())
{
}
```

Your View will now generate an exception when some association is loaded lazily because the DataContext will be disposed by now and unavailable for database operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I'm not using LINQ-to-SQL and there's no lazy loading happening in my View, your post inspired me to try a few other things which leaded to a partial explanation.

Answer (score 0):

get .NET 4.0 beta and VS 2010 beta, and use

> Parallel.Foreach()

Edit: the above answer was supposed to be slightly *sarcastic*.  Although it's not a true solution, once you reap the benefits of the TPL in VS 2010, you'll see what I mean.

In reality, what are you looping over, and what are you doing in your loop exactly, it really depends on your code structure, your data structures, etc.  Need more information for a less-sarcastic answer than the above.

Comment: Well, twice as fast as "dog slow" is still rather slow. Not a solution to a problem, but a solution to a symptom.

Comment: I don't know that moving to Parallel computing if the solution.

Comment: @JulianR - 1000 times faster than "dog slow" doesn't improve the complexity of a general problem, but I'd definitely prefer using the 1000 x faster version any day.

Comment: Besides, this kinda kills the ordering as order is not guaranteed when executed in parallel. Sure, you can do in-order parallelism with the TPL, but that does cost a good chunk of the performance gains. :p

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally clicked on the Vote arrows and now the site won't let me take away the -1 vote!

Answer (score 0):

Does it really happen only in view? Maybe during iteration You perform database loading which slows whole process down. Do You have some kind of lazy loading implemented? You should check database activity during that process.

Comment: Yes, the performance problem is just in one loop in a View.  I've used Fiddler to check if my View has any database activity, and it doesn't.  Thanks for your post though.

Comment: @Slack: How is fiddler going to help you check db activity?